# Autofac - resolving type or types implementing same interface at runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, autofac

I am new to using IoC/DI and I am learning about Autofac to use it in my Xamarin Form, C# project.  I am reading Autofac documentation (https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html#application-execution)and I am confused about a statement relating to the Application Execution section where it says:

"*Later, if you want your application to write a different date, you could implement a different IDataWriter and then change the registration at startup. ...*"

I am confused about this because it says that if I want different IDataWritter, I need to **change** the registration at startup.

What if I dont know which implementation of IDataWritter I want to use at startup.  For example, I have IDataWritter interface implemented by ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC and at run time, I have to somehow resolve one of the 3 or maybe all 3 of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a nice question :) But it's also a trap :) Nonetheless, I will spring the trap and answer based on my own experience, and accept the backlash this might generate.

So in your question you describe different scenarios, but the main question could be the 'what if I don't know which implementation I want to use at startup'. And in my experience, this is rarely the case for a well-designed system.

When trying to understand DI in general for me it helped a lot to think about it outside of software engineering terms. DI is basically nothing more than applying interfaces to help your components work together; a principle that is applied in other engineering fields as well.

Let's take an example: if you take a motherboard, it has sockets for the different components that basically make up a PC: it has a socket for a CPU, a socket for a graphics card etc. And then you have actual CPUs made by Intel or AMD that are compatible with the socket that can be plugged in. And you have graphics cards made by Nvidia or ATI (do they still exists? :) ), that can be plugged in. It's the same principle: the motherboard could be a concrete class in your application, the sockets are actual C# language interfaces (you didn't explicitly state it, I'm assuming C#), these are injected to your concrete class (e.g. via constructor injection), and then you have other classes that implement the interfaces (the 'sockets') that are registered at startup.

I explained this analogy to support my argument: if you have a motherboard that you want to use for your PC, you have to assemble all the components before you start up your system. The same goes for DI as well: it's not the magic of DI that you can change your components whenever you want. The magic in DI is that if you change a component, that should not affect another component. That is, if you want to plug in a different graphics card, you do not have to rebuild your whole motherboard (and with that, possibly the other components).

That being said, there really are some scenarios where the examples you give come up and you have to somehow trick the system (most commonly in plug-in based systems). After all if my analogy is extended to USB or HDMI, we have plug-and-play devices that doesn't require you to shut down and then change something. But to split hairs, these are not really dependencies of a PC, just optional extra peripherals, so they should be treated in a different way. But to not split hairs and again acknowledge that in some situations this dynamic nature is needed, here's some other resources that you should look into (Note that these are Autofac-specific implementations, but most DI containers have similar features):

- [The enumeration implicit relationship type](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b) allows you to resolve all the components registered to a service at runtime.
- [Keyed service lookup](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#keyed-service-lookup-iindex-x-b) allows you to add a key to your registrations and resolve the service by that key; i.e. you can choose the component for a service from a "service dictionary".
- [Assembly scanning](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html) allows you to just specify an assembly and get the component from that assembly for a given service. This is probably the most dynamic method to resolve components; I have used this in plug-in based systems.

Comment: Thank you, love the way you put it down